# How to correctly compile a nodejs package before installing it?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to fix a bug in a [cspell package which fails to install from git clone](https://github.com/Jason3S/cspell/issues/53) and I am facing a conundrum.

I found that the installation expects to copy files from dist/ folder which does not exist in a clean clone because is produced by running `npm compile`

So I decided to add this into `package.json` scripts section:

```
"preinstall": "npm run compile"
```

Mainly before running install, it should run compile, which I know to be producing the desired files.

Now I faced a new problem: compile fails because of missing "tsc" command. I looked and apparently this is provided by `typescript` package which was listed as a devDependency. Because it was missing i suspected that it was not installed because install was supposed to install only runtime dependencies and I decided to try to move it there. Bad luck, doing this was not enough, which means that `preinstall` is run before installing any dependencies.

What is the magic needed for fixing installation from source, without adding extra manual steps between clone and install command?

Comment: If you're trying to compile everything before you install stuff, then of course you're going to have problems. I took a look at the package.json - I don't understand why it would be wanting to copy some files?

Comment: I am not the author or maintainer of the package and nodejs is not really listed on my skill list, thus is why I ended asking here. But feel free to add questions to the the bug I linked, the author is active and willing to help. BTW, I corrected the link to https://github.com/Jason3S/cspell/issues/53

Comment: @estus Thanks for the updates and please feel free to comment on the lined ticket #53 as I think the package would need a bit of rework in order to make it installable from source. Some comments could help the author going in the right direction. As you noted it should never have a bin that does not exist in the repo. After installation, it may be able to build and use it, which makes me think that the bin should be a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You should install global for `typescript`.

Or create script `postinstall` run before start main script but after install all package.